# Call method with parameters and get return value from dynamic user control

Tags: asp.net

I load user control in my page with following code:

```
UserControl com = (UserControl)LoadControl("~/Sample.ascx");
pnlLoadCom.Controls.Add(com);
```

I want to call the method from all dynamic User controls, with parameters, and get the return value from this method when I click button on my page. How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? To achieve what?

Comment: Have u tried to define/cast as actual UserControl's class instead of generic UserControl?

Comment: I have many control user . I want add dynamic add they with click on their name . and when i click on button , i get parameter string of value for save to database .